# How to return error with OUTPUT SQL 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, coldfusion

Hello I have stored procedure that executes simple Insert transaction with try/catch block. If transaction is successful `OUTPUT` will return inserted record ID. If error happens I would like to return content from try/catch block. My current code will return blank RecID in situation when error occurs. Here is my code example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertRecord] 
    @Status BIT = NULL,
    @Name VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @Code CHAR(2) = NULL,
    @ActionID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NULL
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET XACT_ABORT ON
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO dbo.Dictionary(
                Status,Name,Code,ActionDt,ActionID
            )
            OUTPUT INSERTED.RecID
            VALUES(
                @Status,@Name,@Code,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,@ActionID
            );
        END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH 
        SELECT  
            ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
            ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
            ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
            ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage,
            CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DateTime
    END CATCH
```

Here is what code above will return if I try to insert same record that already exist:

```
ErrorProcedure  
InsertRecord    
ErrorLine   
16              
ErrorNumber 
2627
ErrorMessage    
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Code'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Dictionary'. The duplicate key value is (44).
DateTime
2018-08-23 10:46:02.920
```

This is what I expect and this is showing in Management Studio 2008. When I call this procedure with ColdFusion I just get `RecID = ''`. Here is example how I call this procedure:

```
<cftry>
    <cfstoredproc procedure="InsertRecord" datasource="#dsn#">
        <cfprocparam dbvarname="@Status" value="#trim(arguments.frm_status)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit" />
        <cfprocparam dbvarname="@Code" value="#trim(arguments.frm_code)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_char" maxlength="2" null="#!len(trim(arguments.frm_code))#" />
        <cfprocparam dbvarname="@Name" value="#trim(arguments.frm_name)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="50" null="#!len(trim(arguments.frm_name))#" />
        <cfprocparam dbvarname="@ActionID" value="#trim(SESSION.UserID)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_idstamp" maxlength="50" null="#!len(trim(SESSION.UserID))#" />
        <cfprocresult name="Result"/>
    </cfstoredproc>

    <cfset local.fnResults = {status : "200", RecID : Result.RecID}>

    <cfcatch type="any">
        <cfset local.fnResults = {error:cfcatch,status : "400", class : "alert-danger", message : "Error! Please contact your administrator."}>
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

Is there a way to return error from stored procedure to CodlFusion after execution?

Comment: What do you get when you dump out the `Result` variable after the cfstoredproc call?  `<cfdump var="#Result#">` The error is likely stored under some other variable name within that structure.

Comment: @Miguel-F Just `RecID` blank no value.

Comment: That doesn't seem right. The result variable should be a structure containing other information from the stored procedure call. Status, execution time, etc. Note that if the stored procedure returns more than one result set then you need to code one cfprocresult tag per result set.

Comment: @Miguel-F Thats what I thought but if I dump result there is no other information... My procedure looks identical as one above.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually functioning exactly like you wrote it. It's catching the error and outputting your data in the `CATCH` block. If you want to trap for a specific type of error and handle it differently, then you have to specify it. `2627` is your Primary Key Constraint Violation error, but I'm not really sure you want to treat that as an actual error. It would be better to see if your primary key exists first.

Try something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertRecord] 
    @Status BIT = NULL,
    @Name VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @Code CHAR(2) = NULL,
    @ActionID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NULL
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET XACT_ABORT ON
        /* Check if your primary key record exists. */
        IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Dictionary WHERE ActionID = @ActionID) 
          /* Instead of ActionID, use whatever your Primary Key is. */
        BEGIN
            SELECT NULL ;  /* This returns NULL if the primary key record exists. */
        END
        ELSE
        /* PK record does not exist, so try to INSERT. */
        BEGIN TRY
            INSERT INTO dbo.Dictionary(
                Status,Name,Code,ActionDt,ActionID
            )
            OUTPUT INSERTED.RecID
            VALUES(
                @Status,@Name,@Code,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,@ActionID
            );
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH /* INSERT errored, so return the data of what it was. */
            SELECT  
                ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
                ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
                ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
                ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage,
                CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DateTime
        END CATCH
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9601e1c43d38ef551f23f2c866e50b5d

**NOTE:** To trap for a specific error code (you'll have to find the error code you're looking for), use something like:

```
BEGIN CATCH
  IF ERROR_NUMBER() = 2627  /* This is a PK Violation error */
    /* DO YOUR PK VIOLATION STUFF HERE. */
END CATCH
```

Comment: Also note that you might need to do some SQL Locking around that process.

Comment: I think I misread your initial issue. It doesn't appear that your sproc has an OUTPUT variable assigned, so `Result.RecID` wouldn't be populated since nothing was INSERTed on a PK Violation. I guess the `INSERT ...OUTPUT INSERTED....` will still leak out of the sproc in this case. I'll try to do some testing when I get home.  <<< That said, what do you plan to do with your error information if it does error?

Comment: I would like to return error to server side language and if error exist  send a message to the user like I have one in my try catch block. There might be a better way to deal with this but I have validation to prevent this kind of errors. Pk violation was just an example. I'm not sure if inserting errors in the table would be a good option?